# limit of ratio of partition function

Tags: integer-partitions

Does the following limit exists?

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{p(n)}{p(n-5)}$$

where $p(n)$ denote the [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) function.

If this limit exists, is it equal to 1?

Kindly share your thoughts.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $$p(n) \sim \frac{e^{\pi\sqrt{\frac{2n}3}}}{4\sqrt3\,n} $$ compute $\frac{p(n)}{p(n-a)}$, take logarithms and expand as series for large values og $n$. This would give
$$\log \left(\frac{p(n)}{p(n-a)}\right)=\frac{\pi  a}{\sqrt{6n}}-\frac{a}{2
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)$$ and continuing with Taylor series using $x=e^{\log(x)}$, then
$$\frac{p(n)}{p(n-a)}=1+\frac{\pi  a }{\sqrt{6n}}+\frac{a \left(\pi ^2 a-6\right)}{12
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)$$ which shows the limit (already given in answers) but also a quite good approximation of the ratio.

Using $n=50$ and $a=5$, the exact value is $\frac{102113}{44567}\approx 2.291$ while the above expansion would give $\frac{114+20 \sqrt{3} \pi +5 \pi ^2}{120} \approx 2.268$

Comment: Thank you. Very insightful.

Answer (score 1):

$p(n) \sim \frac1{4\sqrt3n} e^{\pi\sqrt{2n/3}}$ according to [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A000041) and GTM177 Chapter II.
Hence, $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{p(n)}{p(n-5)}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac1{4\sqrt3n} e^{\pi\sqrt{2n/3}}}{\frac1{4\sqrt3(n-5)} e^{\pi\sqrt{2(n-5)/3}}}=1$$